# stof()/stoi() with dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, casting, stl, std

I have my own type

```
namespace FaF
{
    // Allocator is my own Memory Allocator for STL
    using string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
}

FaF::string number("1234");
stoi( (const std::string &) number);  <-- error
```

using `stoi(number) aka FaF::string&` results in this error when running `gcc` with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` switches:

> error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing
>   rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]

I tried lot of castings but nothing helped. More or less `std::string` and `FaF::string` *are* the same types *apart* from the Memory Allocator.

**My question:** How can I fix this keeping using the `stoi()/stof()` functions?

**Update::** Yes, of course, I could use `atoi( number.c_str() )` but I want to understand the problem here.

Comment: You have the key: the two types are not the same, period. You can't cast one to the other. This is not just a theoretical issue, for example, it is possible that `sizeof(std::allocator<...>) != sizeof(your::Allocator)`

Comment: @erenon OK, this means I have to write my own version of `stoi()/stof()` like `FaF::stoi()/FaF::stof()` ?

Comment: as an alternative, you could also copy your string into a regular one.

Comment: @erenon Yes, I was thinking about this but I think it is better I wrap it into my own `namespace` and `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *studying* the defintion of `std::stoi` in `basic_string.h`:

```
inline int
stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int>(&std::strtol, "stoi", __str.c_str(),
                    __idx, __base); }
```

it was then easy to write my own - more general - version:

```
namespace FaF
{
  template<typename T>
  inline int
  stoi(const T& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
  { return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int>(&std::strtol, "stoi", __str.c_str(),
                    __idx, __base); }
}
```

This test script

```
FaF::string numberFaF( "1234" );
std::string numberStd( "4321" );
printf( "stoi<FaF::string>=%d - stoi<std::string>=%d\n", 
              FaF::stoi( numberFaF ), FaF::stoi( numberStd ) );
```

compiles and produces the expected result:

```
stoi<FaF::string>=1234 - stoi<std::string>=4321
```

I am just wondering why there is not already a general version. Almost everything in STL is implemented as a template and this simple function is *hard coded* to `std::string`...

Comment: "*it was then easy to write my own - more general - version:*" Which only works on that one implementation, since you're calling non-standard functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas ?? I don't understand. It is the exactly copy from `basic_string.h` delivered with gcc - just wrapping it into a template.

Comment: Yes; that's the problem. It will *only work* with GCC. `__gnu_cxx` doesn't exist in, for example, libc++.

Comment: @NicolBolas :-); I got you now. Due to the environment I am *married* with gcc. This is a very special project which is not going to be deployed on other systems. That far it is ok for me. Thx for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

This is an unfortunate problem with the `sto*` class of functions; they *only* work with `std::string`. Even though they don't care what allocator you're using, that's still part of the type, so it still matters to C++. Nor can you pretend that a `basic_string` that uses a different allocator is a `std::string`.

Until C++17 [solves this problem (kinda)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r2.html), you'll have to deal with it manually:

```
stoi({number.data(), number.size()});
```

Comment: Could you summarize shortly how C++17 solves this problem? What is the code snippet for C++17?

Answer (score 1):

Use `c_str` and atoi instead:

```
FaF::string number("1234");
int result = atoi(number.c_str()); // result == 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your string with sto* functions. If you take a look at the docs (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), you will find that function's signature takes exactly std::string. where

```
std::string = std::basic_string<char, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>>
```

I'd like to bring to your attention that it uses standart allocator. So in fact your string is not the same as std::string.

As a workaround, you can specify std::string operator.

```
struct string : public std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>
{
    // will produce a copy. use const char* instead
    explicit operator std::string()
    {
        return c_str();
    }
    explicit operator const char*()
    {
        return c_str();
    }
};
```

usage example:

```
FaF::string number( "1435151315" );
std::cout << std::stoi( static_cast< std::string >( number ) );
std::cout << std::atoi( static_cast< const char* >( number ) );
```

PS: don't use C-style casts! :)

I hope it helps.